# Determine positive trend in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have following dataframe and would like to determine a positive trend with combination of keyword and id

```
keyword id  rank date
--------------------------
test    185 45  11/3/2001
test    999 44  11/3/2001
test    810 43  11/3/2001
test    442 42  11/3/2001
test    188 41  11/3/2001
test    185 45  11/3/2001
test    999 41  11/3/2004
test    810 43  11/3/2001
test    442 42  11/3/2001
test    188 41  11/3/2001
test    185 48  20/04/2002
test    185 90  20/05/2003 


data = data.groupby(['keyword', 'id'])
```

Output
Ex:

```
test    185    positive(1)
test    999    negative(-1)
```

Comment: What is the expected output? Can you also craft a meaningful example? Grouping by keyword/id would make little sense here as all group would only have 1 item

Comment: updated data and expected out

Comment: what is there is a mixed trend? Part increasing, part decreasing?

Comment: yes that's also possible.. i mean no trend

Comment: So, as output only strictly positive or negative, else drop?

Comment: I also assumed the last column was mistakenly labeled "rank" (modified to "date")

Answer (score 1):

Using `diff`, aggregation as set and `map`:

```
import numpy as np

trend = {frozenset([1]): 'positive', frozenset([-1]): 'negative'}

(df.groupby(['keyword', 'id'])['rank']
    # compute the sign of diff, keep only 1/-1 and aggregate as frozenset
   .agg(lambda x: frozenset(np.sign(x.diff().iloc[1:]))-{0})
    # map 1 to "positive", -1 to "negative"
    # mixed 1/-1 would be NaN, drop them
   .map(trend).dropna()
)
```

output:

```
keyword  id 
test     185    positive
         999    negative
Name: rank, dtype: object
```